# Alpha channel in Arcgis Image Service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, image-service

I have an issue to enable alpha channel in arcgis image service.

Image service published from a mosaic dataset in sde DB. The image files are geotiff images with 2 bands. First band supposed to be grey value and second - alpha channel. I use extract band function (with parameter "1 1 1 2") in function chain of image service and it returns 4 bands as i want. But the alpha band still not activated - returned image is just first three band raster with no alpha.

In client i tried to set raster format to "png32" but it not help.

As alternative I published Map Service of this mosaic dataset and manually activate alpha channel in symbology tab. But I want an image service with alpha channel not a map service.

Any suggestions?

*ArcGIS 10.3